# Android Unit Testing: Cucumber-jvm + Android Instrumentation

Tags: android, android-testing, cucumber-jvm

**Using: Cucumber-JVM with Android Instrumentation + Espresso).**

**Reference Github link**: https://github.com/mfellner/cucumber-android for this. The simple sample works fine.

**Problem with cucumber-jvm + android instrumentation:**
But in the sample in link, it uses ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 which is deprecated. I would like to use @Rule - ActivityTestRule class as said by Google.

**Here my question is:**
       For using cucumber-jvm, I am using the CucumberInstrumentationCore instead of 
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner".

So Android junit annotations like @Rule for ActivityTestRule is not parsed by CucumberInstrumentation. So Is it possible to overcome this problem?

Then is my decision to use cucumber-jvm + android instrumentation has to be reverted back. My question is not only for the deprecated class but globally is it good idea to go for cucumber-jvm + android instrumentation, as it can't use instrumentation features because of annotation parsing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your runner should inherit from Android JUnitRunner:

```
public class Instrumentation extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

private final CucumberInstrumentationCore instrumentationCore = new CucumberInstrumentationCore(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {
    instrumentationCore.create(bundle);
    super.onCreate(bundle);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    waitForIdleSync();
    instrumentationCore.start();
}
```

Pay attention to the super class been initialized at the end of onCreate.

Then, edit your defaultConfig in your build.grade file:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your.package.name"

    testApplicationId "your.steps.package"
    testInstrumentationRunner "your.package.Instrumentation"     
}
```

And finally, the steps definition class, which inherited from ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 should look like:

```
public class BaseStepDefinitions {
public static final String TAG = BaseStepDefinitions.class.getSimpleName();

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<StartupActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(StartupActivity.class);


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mActivityRule.launchActivity(null);
    mActivityRule.getActivity();
}

/**
 * All the clean up of application's data and state after each scenario must happen here
 */
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {

}

@When("^I login with \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void i_login_with_and(String user, String password) throws Throwable {
   // Login...
}
```

The setUp function runs before each scenario, and launching the activity.

Globally, if it serves your needs I don't see any problem using it like so, both Cucumber annotations and the JUnit annotations can be parsed in this way.

I've created a sample project: [github.com/Clutcha/EspressoCucumber](http://github.com/Clutcha/EspressoCucumber)

Comment: AndroidJUnitRunner is one that parses the Junit annotations. If I use AndroidJunitRunner, it will not parse my feature file, stepdefn, and cucumber annotations.

Comment: If you will look in the onCreate method you will see the following line: instrumentationCore.create(bundle); which initializing the cucumber runner and in the onStart method there is a call to the cucumber: instrumentationCore.start(); which will look and parse the cucumber annotations. Also, like you said, I inherit from AndroidJUnit and calling its base class after the cucumber initalization to parse the JUnit annotations.

Comment: Let me try and let you know. But sounds Okay

Comment: I have tried and it is not recognising the feature files whereas when i remove AndroidJunitRunner it runs. hav u tried it and is it working for u

Comment: Yes. It's working for me. I can upload a sample project to github if you want.

Comment: I have tried your sample and works fine. Thanks for sharing the code. I have one more doubt in implementation. BaseSteps has ActivityTestRule and launchingActivity method is called explicitly. My Question is "how  is BaseStep's ActivityTestRule is executed, considering the LoginSteps hasn't extended. is it only because stepdefn package name is given as com.example.app.stepDefinitions ??

Comment: The ActivityTestRule is executed in the setUp method in the BaseSteps file. It runs before each test because I'm using Cucumber's @Before annotation. And Yes your assumption is right, the com.example.app.stepDefinitions tells the Cucumber framework where to search for the test functions.

Comment: @SagiKovo I just check out the code and it is not running  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2".. It is throwing me an error java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered

Comment: @SagiKovo Your  `Instrumentation` class may well inherit from `AndroidJUnitRunner`, however what I think you will find is that `JUnit` tests in your `androidTest` folder will not run.