# Cucumber hooks control flow?

Tags: android-espresso, cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to write automated UI tests using Espresso and Cucumber. So far I've managed to successfully execute step definitions for a feature that tests a single activity using `ActivityTestRule`. I use Cucumber's `@Before` annotation to prepare for the scenario, for example launch the required activity. The issue is that when I try to execute a test suite containing more than one feature definition all `@Before` blocks will be called before every scenario. For example when the instrumentation core starts executing scenario 1, it executes the `@Before` methods both in scenario 1 and scenario 2 resulting in overlapping activity launches and failing tests.

```
public class Activity1Stepdefs {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Called before both scenario 1 and scenario 2, needs to be called only before scenario 1. 
    }

    @Given("^scenario 1$")
    public void scenario_1() throws Throwable {
        // Scenario 1
    }
}

public class Activity2Stepdefs {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Called before both scenario 1 and scenario 2, needs to be called only before scenario 2. 
    }

    @Given("^scenario 2$")
    public void scenario_2() throws Throwable {
        // Scenario 2
    }
}
```

Resulting control flow:

1. `Activity1Stepdefs.setUp()`
2. `Activity2Stepdefs.setUp()`
3. `Activity1Stepdefs.scenario_1()`
4. `Activity2Stepdefs.setUp()`
5. `Activity1Stepdefs.setUp()`
6. `Activity2Stepdefs.scenario_2`

Desired control flow:

1. `Activity1Stepdefs.setUp()`
2. `Activity1Stepdefs.scenario_1()`
3. `Activity2Stepdefs.setUp()`
4. `Activity2Stepdefs.scenario_2`

Comment: This is normal behavior of before hooks. If you want to use different before hooks. Then convert before scenario into step definition and add it into scenario as story line in feature file. Don't use before scenario if you want different behavior of it.

Comment: But I keep seeing examples of people launching activities in `@Before` hooks like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36012553/5963217 So I guess my question is: What would be the correct place to prepare the UI for the test then? I really wouldn't want my features to be polluted with setup logic.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by tagged hooks. First assign tags for scenario 1 and 2 in the feature file then create tagged hooks as give below. 
Assume I have given tag name for scenario 1 and 2 as scen1 and scen2 respectively.
 `before ("@scen1") 
    public void scenarioOneSetup()
{ // code for scenario 1 setup } 
before ("@scen2") 
public void scenarioTwoSetup()
{// code for scenario 2 setup}`